# algolia: restore to an earlier version of an index (i accidentally uploaded to the wrong index)

Tags: indexing, algolia

i am not a coder lol! `hi world` i uploaded a list from CSV to algolia index but accidentally uploaded it to the wrong index title. the list is ≈ 400 entries so it would take way too long to delete the wrong ones manually. i don't want to delete the entire list, just the ones i accidentally uploaded. any way to streamline this? as in restore to a former version of the index? or rapidly delete ≈ 400 entires? thanks internet.
i tried to go through manually and delete all of the entries but it takes entirely way too long. it's like i'm doing that on a dialup connection :'(. would appreciate any tips here to a lover of all things internet, but non-coder.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it depends.

Long answer: if you have uploaded your records in a single batch, you can find this upload operation from your Algolia Dashboard. From here, the response contains all the `objectID` values of the added records. Using that list of `objectID`, you can then use the client of your choice and use the list as a parameter of the `DeleteObjects` function which exactly does what you want.

**Edit:** I've just checked and we're only storing the first 2KB of the JSON body, meaning that if the response was bigger than that, you won't be able to retrieve all the objects anyway.

However, if you uploaded those elements separately, you'll have to do it by hand.

If you need help with that, don't hesitate to contact us at support@algolia.com, we would be happy to help you. :)